# Laravel Collections: Filter with two cloumns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-collection

So let's just begin with the question.

I have a database with following structure:

| id | first_user_id | second_user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |

And let's say i have a variable with `id=1`
`$id = 1`

I find the needed records with this.

```
Model::where('status',1)
->where('first_user_id', $id)
->orWhere('second_user_id',$id)->get();
```

I want to get all of the ids that is not equals to the `$id` in some of the columns.

For exampe:

```
if first_user_id is equals to $id
    return second_user_id column
if second_user_id is equals to $id
    return first_user_id column
```

I want to done that with [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) if it is possible?

The result must be array with the ids from condition above.

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2 // second_user_id from first record
    [1] => 2 // first_user_id from the last record.
)
```

For more clearly here is some pseudo php code for what i exactly want

```
<?php

$students = [
  [
    "first_user_id" => 1,
    "second_user_id" => 2
  ],
    [
    "first_user_id" => 2,
    "second_user_id" => 3
  ],
    [
    "first_user_id" => 1,
    "second_user_id" => 3
  ],
    [
    "first_user_id" => 4,
    "second_user_id" => 6
  ],
];


$var = 2; // Authenticated user
$arr = [];
foreach($students as $student) {
  if($student['first_user_id'] == $var || $student['second_user_id'] == $var) {
    if($student['first_user_id'] == $var) {
      $arr[] = $student['second_user_id'];
    } else $arr[] = $student['first_user_id'];
  }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hope you want this one `Model::where('status',1)->orWhere('first_user_id', '!=', $id)->orWhere('second_user_id', '!=', $id)->get()->toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use [union](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions) in that case

```
$first = DB::table('users')
            ->where('second_user_id',$id)
            ->select('first_user_id as user_id');

$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('first_user_id',$id)
            ->select('second_user_id as user_id')
            ->union($first)
            ->get(['user_id']);
```

In SQL it would be like

```
select first_user_id as user_id from users where second_user_id = :id
union
select second_user_id as user_id from users where first_user_id = :id
```